# Is there a way to fill a column in one Dataframe with a column from a second Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, match, fill

Objective: to fill the value of a column in 1 Dataframe from values of a 2nd DF.

I have a Dataframe with the following:

DF1

| ID | ValueA | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaaaaa | Na | 02/13 |
| Bbbbbb | Na | 03/13 |
| Cccccc | Na | 04/13 |
| Aaaaaa | Na | 03/14 |

DF2

| ID | ValueA | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaaaaa | 12 | 02/13 |
| Bbbbbb | 19 | 03/13 |
| Aaaaaa | 15 | 03/14 |
| Cccccc | 13 | 04/13 |

I would like to place ValueA from DF2 into valueA of DF1, with match ID and Dates of each entry without it causing an offset because they may not be in the same order which is the current issue I am getting.

DF1$ValueA <- DF2$ValueA

does not seem to do what I want. I have also tried to fuse to tables with no luck.

Any help of direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to join the tables using `merge` or `dplyr`'s `left_join`

Comment: What about if I don't have the same # of columns in both DFs? Thanks for your reply and time!

Comment: It would still work. Although depending on what exactly you want to do with your data you can choose either a left_join, right_join, full_join, or inner_join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `dplyr` `rows_update` -

```
DF1 <- dplyr::rows_update(DF1, DF2, by = c('ID', 'Dates'))
DF1

#      ID ValueA Dates
#1 Aaaaaa     12 02/13
#2 Bbbbbb     19 03/13
#3 Cccccc     13 04/13
#4 Aaaaaa     15 03/14
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = c("Aaaaaa", "Bbbbbb", "Cccccc", "Aaaaaa"), 
    ValueA = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Dates = c("02/13", "03/13", "04/13", "03/14")), 
   row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(ID = c("Aaaaaa", "Bbbbbb", "Aaaaaa", "Cccccc"), 
    ValueA = c(12L, 19L, 15L, 13L), Dates = c("02/13", "03/13", 
    "03/14", "04/13")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry about the data formatting, and thank you for your reply! Would this also work if DF1 had more columns/variables than DF2?

Comment: I tried the code, and keep getting an error: `x` key values are not unique? Do you know what might be causing this ?